# MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException when updating Jersey to 2.22.2

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a working app with Jersey 2.8, that I'm trying to upgrade to 2.22.2. But when I do that, Jersey keeps throwing these exceptions:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.
```

I even manually added the jackson dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But it doesn't help.

I'm using Spring Boot and this is my config class:

```
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("com.xxxxxx.resource", "com.xxxxx.provider");
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        register(LoggingFilter.class);
        this.property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
        this.property(ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, true);
        this.property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
    }

}
```

And the relevant parts of my pom.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more than just Jackson (core), which is just a serialization framework, but but does not provided any mechanism to bind into the Jersey framework. For serialization, Jersey uses `MessageBodyReader`s and `MessageBodyWriter`s. There is a Jackson module that takes core Jackson and uses it to create a `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` for JSON for JAX-RS

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Jersey has a module that add some more to that library, and does some auto registration. That artifact is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the one you should use, if you are working with Jersey. You don't need to do anything else after you add it. It automatically register the Jackson providers

Note that the `jersey-media-json-jackson` pulls in all the required Jackson libraries, but it will not be latest version of Jackson. With Jersey 2.22.2, I think the Jackson version is 2.5 (not 100% sure). If you need the latest features, you should exclude all the Jackson libraries, and add the first one in this answer, with the version you want, along with the above one. These are the exclusions you should make to `jersey-media-json-jackson

```
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>

<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>

<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
```

Comment: Thanks again. Any idea why it happens when upgrading?

Comment: If you accept a POJO parameter or return a POJO response, Jersey needs to JSON provider to handle the serialization, not just the Jackson core. If you serialize it yourself with core Jackson, i.e. you just have a String method parameter (then use Jackson to deserialize) or returning a String after using Jackson to serialize, then Jersey doesn't need to a provider. It just sends the or receives the String as is. That's the only thing I can think of that you were doing differently. Other than that, with just the dependencies in your post, just changing the version to 2.8, I don't see how it...

Comment: ... would work with POJOs. There is no provider to handle the POJOs